# Download de uma tabela de um site em formato de data.frame no R

Tags: r

Boa noite

Preciso fazer o download da tabela intitulada **Indicadores fundamentalistas** no link a seguir

```
http://www.fundamentus.com.br/detalhes.php?papel=PETR4
```

Pretendo baixar de todos os ativos da bolsa através de um looping usando como base um vetor com os códigos de todas as ações

Porém não sei como baixar a tabela via R em formato de um data frame

Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa resposta tem muito a ver com raspagem de dados da web e uso de expressões regulares. Eu não sou um expert no 1º, uso o 2º, mas acredito que posso lhe ajudar.

Para baixar o banco de dados, você precisa usar a função `htmltab::htmltab`:

```
library(htmltab)
a <- htmltab("http://www.fundamentus.com.br/detalhes.php?papel=PETR4", which = 3)
```

O argumento which = 3 indica qual tabela é para ser baixada, nesse caso, a 3ª. A partir disso, você pode usar os laços que você precisa, e fazer uma edição básica da tabela para ficar do jeito que você precisa:

```
b <- a[, c(3,4)]
a <- rbind(b, a[, c(5,6)])
names(a) <- c("Indicadores", "Valor")
a$Indicadores <- gsub("\\?", "", a$Indicadores)
a <- na.omit(a)
row.names(a) <- NULL
a
       Indicadores Valor
1              P/L 13,72
2             P/VP  1,28
3           P/EBIT  3,58
4              PSR  1,01
5         P/Ativos  0,41
6      P/Cap. Giro  7,60
7  P/Ativ Circ Liq -0,82
8       Div. Yield  3,3%
9        EV / EBIT  6,30
10     Giro Ativos  0,41
11  Cres. Rec (5a) -0,5%
12             LPA  1,98
13             VPA 21,25
14     Marg. Bruta 35,6%
15      Marg. EBIT 28,2%
16   Marg. Líquida  7,6%
17    EBIT / Ativo 11,5%
18            ROIC 12,7%
19             ROE  9,3%
20   Liquidez Corr  1,48
21  Div Br/ Patrim  1,18
```

Por fim, tu precisaria arrumar a coluna Valor, pois tem índices que são em %, e outros que aparentemente não são.

Comment: Excelente, parabéns, ajudou muito, obrigado

Comment: Não está mais funcionando aqui. Agora, ao executar o htmltab, dá o erro: 

    No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
    Error: Couldn't find the table. Try passing (a different) information to the which argument.
    In addition: Warning message:
    XML content does not seem to be XML: ''

Alguém sabe como contornar isso ?

Obg,